# Rails/RSpec: 'get' to a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have the following in my Rails 3 controllers/application.rb (which I'm trying to write a spec for):

```
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:alert] = t(:access_denied)
    if (current_user) then
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      session[:direct_redirect] = request.url
      redirect_to new_user_session_url
    end
  end
```

I'd like to write some specs to ensure the functionality works. I've placed the tests in spec/controller/application_controller_spec.rb, and figure I should write something such as:

```
  it "should redirect to the root url" do
    controller.stub(:authorize!) { raise CanCan::AccessDenied }
    get :index
    response.should redirect_to(root_url)
  end
```

The problem is that get :index line. The spec throws back a 'no route matches controller => application" error. "Fair enough", I figured, and tried to route to a different controller. Attempts were:

```
* get :controller => 'purchases', :action => :index
* get purchases_url
* get '/purchases/'
```

All of which where interpreted as an action under the 'application' controller.

So, how can I route to a controller in rspec apart from the one in which the spec is written?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To test that kind of thing you're going to want to use anonymous controllers within RSpec. [Relish has a fantastic example here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) about them.

Be sure to have a look around in other parts of that documentation too. I've learned a lot by just going through the examples they have there.

Comment: @PlankTon can you post a final example of how you got this working? I am totally stuck on it too.

Comment: @chrishough I'd encourage you to open a new question for that.

Comment: @RyanBigg agreed, I am going to try a few more things than open another ? if I need to.

Comment: You would think this would be a simple thing to do, but the example is seems very convoluted. This makes me sad.

Comment: How is `controller do end` convoluted? It's actually one of the simplest ways of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

In your spec:

```
@controller = ADifferentController.new
expect(@controller).to receive(:this_other_thing)
get :index # or whatever
```